# How to create, write, and read a file on Android and then access it on the device?

Tags: android, file, text-files, saving-data

I'm trying to access a text file on my android device. I have successfully written to and read from the file in my code, but I want to be able to access the file so that I can copy and move it elsewhere.

My code is included below and there are no errors when I run it. However, it is just the base code that I have made numerous edits to, to try and solve this.

Though it is not shown, the default method onCreate runs createFile(), writeFile("Hello File!"), and readFile() all in order after the default code that is contained in the method.

```
Context context = this;

String autoFileName = "AutoDataFile.txt";
File path;
File myFile;

String insideText = "NOTHING";

public void createFile(){
    path = context.getFilesDir();
    myFile = new File(path, autoFileName);
}

public void writeFile(String text){
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        stream.write(text.getBytes());
        stream.write(",".getBytes());
        stream.write("Second input!".getBytes());
        stream.close();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS?: MAY HAVE WRITTEN TO FILE");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR: DID NOT WRITE TO FILE");
    }
}

public void readFile(){
    try {
        Scanner fileStream = new Scanner(myFile);
        insideText += " " + fileStream.useDelimiter(",").nextLine();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS?: MAY HAVE READ FROM FILE");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR: DID NOT READ FROM FILE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to write a file, to read it and/or move it ? I'm asking because maybe you can do whatever you want to do in a different way.

Comment: The plan is to get data from the app in a text file, plug it into a computer, and drag and drop it onto there. Then I can take it and import it into an excel file. I want to do it this way because it is simple and I can't really do anything more complicated because I won't have an internet connection when this process occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

To your build.gradle

```
compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
```

Then add to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then make your file like so:

```
public void writeCSV(ArrayList<String> content) {
    //Point a directory to the external storage
    File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }
    //formatter for the date associated with the file name
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    //inner file to be the location of the csv 
    File csv = new File(exportDir, "csvdata_" + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".csv");
    try {
        //create the file and the writer which will append our data
        csv.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));
         //loop through some desired content
        for (String s : content) {
           //writes the string and separates by a comma (spreadsheet format)
           writer.writeNext(s);
        }
        //close the writer
        writer.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} //end
```

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried this and I still can't find the file anywhere. I can't even find the com.appname.android folder. Is there a way to do this without rooting your phone? I would think so?

Comment: should be My Files -> Device Storage and scroll to the bottom